# shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText: not being called?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uitextinput

I have a custom text view I made using `CoreText` which implements `UITextInput` to handle multi stage input on Japanese and Chinese keyboards. I'm trying to limit the number of characters that can be typed into the text view using `shouldChangeTextInRange:replacementText:` and I'm noticing that it's only called when a key on the keyboard is pushed, but not when a button on the thing above the keyboard which offers replacement suggestions is pushed (example below).

[image]

Does anyone know why this is and if there are any similar methods I can implement that will be called when a suggestion above the keyboard is pushed (so I can block them from being set as marked text)?